# tPHPMyAdmin Procedures?

Tags: phpmyadmin, procedure

Does "Procedure"s will be installed with PHPMyAdmin by default on a Linux cPanel server?
My PHPMyAdmin does not support "Procedure"s by default but one of my customers says that it's not true and it should be installed with PHPMyAdmin by defualt!

Answer (score 0):

phpMyAdmin does work with procedures. You can create, edit, delete, and execute them through the phpMyAdmin interface.

I'm not sure what you mean by installed with phpMyAdmin by default, though. phpMyAdmin doesn't come with any pre-built procedures, because that would require knowledge of your database structure. You just create them yourself. There's no installation involved any more than when you, say, create a new database.